# Reactjs handleChange for input field in a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm having this scenario (https://codesandbox.io/s/l9ynp52z97) where I want to build a form that needs to have a few email inputs (right now the number is limited to 1), but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because I can't enter anything in the box. Before creating the FormBlock component, it was working, but now, when I'm using props, it is not working anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in the `handleChange` function as the `onChange` prop, but you are using `this.props.handleChange` in the component.

Change to `this.props.onChange` and it will work fine.

```js
<FormControl
  type="email"
  name={this.props.name}
  value={this.props.value}
  onChange={this.props.onChange}
  className={this.props.className}
/>
```